# Automate generation of function template specialization in cpp

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have a list of templated operations with the same signature. I want to read the type of template parameters and the operation as an input from user, and then call the corresponding template specialization. Right now my solution is a long list of nested switch cases and looks as follows

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, unsigned L>
int square() {
    T num = 1;
    for(unsigned l = 0; l < L; ++l){
        num += 1;
        std::cout << num*num << "\n";
    }
}

template<typename T, unsigned L>
int cube(){
    T num = 1;
    for(unsigned l = 0; l < L; ++l){
        num += 1;
        std::cout << num*num*num << "\n";
    }
}
/*..
template<typename T, unsigned L>
int nextOp(){
    stuff...
}
..*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int type = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    int len = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    int opType = std::stoi(argv[3]);

    switch (opType){
        case 2: // op type 2
        switch(type){
            case 0: // datatype 0
            switch(len){
                case 1: // length 1
                    square<int, 1>();
                    break;
                case 2: // length 2
                    square<int, 2>();
            }
            break;
    
            case 1: // datatype 1
            switch(len){
                case 1:
                    square<float,1>();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    square<float, 2>();
                
            }
        }
        break;

        case 3: // op type 3
        switch(type){
            case 0:
            switch(len){
                case 1:
                    cube<int, 1>();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cube<int, 2>();
            }
            break;
    
            case 1:
            switch(len){
                case 1:
                    cube<float,1>();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cube<float, 2>();
                
            }
        }
        /*..
        repeat same nested switch with nextOp<type, len> ??
        ..*/
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Can I for example have some function which takes template function 'op' as an input and generate all the specialization permutations for T and L. But this requires passing a template function as an input which I am not sure is possible to do. Another way could be using macros, but again I am not sure how exactly.   So my question is: What is the best way to generate such template specialization?

Comment: Why template functions instead of regular functions with arguments here? A template argument that's a number is more useful on variable size structures, not as a pseudo-argument.

Comment: There is no better way than a "a long list of nested switch cases", or something logically equivalent. Template parameters are compile-time constants, this is fundamental to C++, there are no workaround or exceptions. To use a particular template value depending on a runtime-only value will require something along the lines of what's shown here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: but we can have one switch by "conversion", not that combination (nested switch).

Comment: @tadman the code I provided is simplified  for ease of understanding. In my actual code type T and unsigned constant L are used as template parameters for classes from a third party library inside the op. I might be wrong, but I think such template arguments have to be know at compile  time and cant be passed as function arguments.

Comment: Remember the compiler can and will deal with arguments like that when compiling, especially if it decides to inline your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might help to avoid nested `switch`:

```
std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>,
             std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2>
> to_int_constant_var(int n)
{
    switch (n) {
        case 1: return std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>();
        case 2: return std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2>();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid argument");
}

std::variant<std::type_identity<int>,
             std::type_identity<float>
> to_type_var(int n)
{
    switch (n) {
        case 0: return std::type_identity<int>();
        case 1: return std::type_identity<float>();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid argument");
}

// We don't have wrapper/container for function template.
// You might turn the function into class functor.
// std doesn't have wrapper around template class, but you might write one if needed
// Here I just call the function and I don't wrap it in any variant.
void call(int op_type, int type, int value)
{
    auto value_c = to_int_constant_var(value);
    auto type_c = to_type_var(type);

    switch (op_type) {
        case 2:
             std::visit([]<typename T, std::size_t N>(
                 std::type_identity<T>,
                 std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>) {
                     square<T, N>();
                  }, type_c, value_c);
             break;
        case 3:
             std::visit([]<typename T, std::size_t N>(
                 std::type_identity<T>,
                 std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>) {
                     cube<T, N>();
                 }, type_c, value_c);
        break;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W7sE7YcWW)